# Is clang-tidy (version 14) right with `bugprone-use-after-move` error on this code?

Tags: c++, c++20, move, clang-tidy

```
struct test {
    test& foo(std::vector<int> const& v) {
        assert(v.size() == 1); return *this; 
    }

    void bar(std::vector<int> v) {}
};

void do_test() {
    std::vector<int> v = { 42 };
    return test{}.foo(v).bar(std::move(v)); // <-- here
}
```

clang-tidy gives an error `bugprone-use-after-move` on "here" string

Why it is use after move?

Comment: Why are you returning something from a void function?

Comment: Returning void is allowed. It has its proposes in templates. Here it doesn't add value though

Comment: @kiner_shah Question is not about it.

Answer (score 4):

Since C++17 it is guaranteed that the *postfix-expression* in a function call, i.e. here `test{}.foo(v).bar` is evaluated before any expression in the argument list.

Therefore the move-construction will happen only after `foo` has returned.

However, before C++17 there was no such guarantee and the move-construction might have happened before the call to `foo`.

It is questionable whether it is a good idea to rely on these new guarantees. Some tools tend to ignore them and continue warning about such code since it would be dangerous if compiled with a different `-std=` flag. GCC does for example the same with its `-Wunsequenced` warnings. There is also the risk that some older compiler versions may still have had bugs in that regard when C++17 was just implemented.

Comment: But this is not _one_ function call, no? First `foo` is evaluated, returning a reference to `this` and that reference is used for a second function call `bar`. `foo` has to return for that reference return value to be set, not? I mean, the optimizer might reorder stuff, but The sequential calls of first `foo` then `bar` must be guaranteed, right? I don't know the standard, but this seems to basic to be unreliable. And I though we could assume arguments are not evaluated until the function is called.

Comment: @JHBonarius Yes, `bar` is guaranteed to be called after `foo` in any C++ version, but that doesn't mean that the constructor for `bar`'s parameter will not be called before both of them. The parameter construction happens in the context of the function containing the `test{}.foo(v).bar(std::move(v));` expression, not as part of the `bar` function call.

Comment: @JHBonarius "_And I though we could assume arguments are not evaluated until the function is called._": That is not the case. Even in current C++ it is not guaranteed that argument expressions are evaluated immediately before the function is called. For example in `f1().g1(h1()) + f2().g2(h2())` the compiler can still call the functions for example in the order `f1 -> f2 -> h1 -> h2 -> g1 -> g2`.

Comment: But at least it is now guaranteed that `h1` comes after `f1` and `h2` after `f2`. That wasn't the case before C++17. As mentioned in the [paper](https://wg21.link/p0145r3) introducing the new guarantee that was really counter-intuitive and something even experts would get wrong in practice (even if they are aware of the rules).

Comment: Wow, that's just nightmare fuel. Thanks for the extended explanation

Answer (score 1):

In

```
foo(v).bar(std::move(v))
```

There are no guarantees(See comments, pre C++17) that the `v` in `foo(v)` will be evaluated before the `std::move(v)` in `bar(std::move(v))`

The [clang-tidy docs](https://releases.llvm.org/11.1.0/tools/clang/tools/extra/docs/clang-tidy/checks/bugprone-use-after-move.html#unsequenced-moves-uses-and-reinitializations) comes with an example of this.

> Unsequenced moves, uses, and reinitializations
>
> In many cases, C++ does not make any guarantees about the order in which sub-expressions of a statement are evaluated. This means that in code like the following, it is not guaranteed whether the use will happen before or after the move:
>
> void f(int i, std::vector v);
> std::vector v = { 1, 2, 3 };
> f(v[1], std::move(v));
>
> In this kind of situation, the check will note that the use and move are unsequenced.
>
> The check will also take sequencing rules into account when reinitializations occur in the same statement as moves or uses. A reinitialization is only considered to reinitialize a variable if it is guaranteed to be evaluated after the move and before the use.

Comment: The rule changed with C++17 for this way of calling functions by member access. Actually a very similar example that had gone unnoticed in Stroustrup's book for a long time was part of the reason for that change, see https://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0145r3.pdf.

Comment: But `f(v[1], std::move(v));` is not the same as `foo(v).bar(std::move(v))`. In the latter, the return value of `foo` has to be evaluated before `bar` may run. These are sequential statements, coupled together.

Comment: @JHBonarius Indeed, but the argument has to be evaluated before the `bar` call.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but not before the `foo` call right? I mean, we should have some guarantees there? I understand the possible out-of-order issue with a _single_ function call, but these are two different functions.

Comment: @JHBonarius My understanding is that pre 17, no guarantees would be made.  See also the samples in user17732522 link. They are also enlightening to the issue.